# Maximo Anywhere

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, maximo, maximo-anywhere

I'm using IBM Maximo Anywhere and I'm new to Maximo  Anywhere. I run Anywhere from my eclipse and test it from IBM worklight simulator. From simulator I can able to login into Anywhere application, But when I create the Ipad environment of my app and install it on Ipad and try to login from Ipad, my Maximo server is on the same network the application is throwing error and not able to login into Anywhere. Can anyone help me please to resolve this issue. I'm also attaching the xcode console log for more information

```
*2016-01-06 17:31:07.741 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: [HANDLER] calling
platform.handlers.LoginHandler.loginClickHandler*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.741 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: Loading message
showed by application = true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.745 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
UserAuthenticationManager - _localAuthentication - vigneshv*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.746 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE] [DATA]
Initializing user profile store with credentials*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.746 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE] list of
previousLoggedUsers: undefined*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.746 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE] user was NOT
successfully authenticated*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.746 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.747 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.747 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.747 WorkExecution[626:200217] ERROR: {"textMsg":"Your
user name and password could not be validated. Connect to the server and
try again."}*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.748 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.748 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.748 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.749 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.750 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.750 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.750 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.751 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
[_realmAuthentication] Authenticating user vigneshv*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.751 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
ServerAuthenticationProvider.login*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.751 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
CustomChallengeHandler login calling submitLoginForm*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.752 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.752 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.752 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.754 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TIMER] _StoreProvider -
wlJsonStoreProvider - closeAll: 55ms*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.759 WorkExecution[626:201158] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request
[login]*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.763 WorkExecution[626:201158] [DEBUG]
[WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] +[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper requestWithURL:]
in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:38 :: Request url is

http://myIPAddress:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/ipad/my_custom_auth_request_url
<http://myIPAddress:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/ipad/my_custom_auth_request_url>*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.768 WorkExecution[626:201158] [DEBUG]
[WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper start] in
WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:183 :: Starting the request with URL

http://myIPAddress:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/ipad/my_custom_auth_request_url
<http://myIPAddress:10080/MaximoAnywhere/apps/services/api/WorkExecution/ipad/my_custom_auth_request_url>*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.780 WorkExecution[626:200217] [DEBUG]
[WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper
requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:215 :: Request Failed*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.782 WorkExecution[626:200217] [DEBUG]
[WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper
requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:216 :: Response Status
Code : 0*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.786 WorkExecution[626:200217] [DEBUG]
[WL_AFHTTPCLIENTWRAPPER_PACKAGE] -[WLAFHTTPClientWrapper
requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPClientWrapper.m:217 :: Response Error :
The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy
requires the use of a secure connection.*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.798 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
CustomChallengeHandler.sendLogin*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.798 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE]
[CustomChallangeHandler.isCustomResponse] false - no response or no JSON
response*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.798 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN:
[_realmAuthentication] Invalid server credentials for user vigneshv*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.798 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: Loading message
showed by application = true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.799 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: Cancel processing
requested*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.799 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE] Closing local
storage*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.800 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.801 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.801 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.802 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.802 WorkExecution[626:200217] === Global promise
rejection handling ===*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.803 WorkExecution[626:200217] === handled: false*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.803 WorkExecution[626:200217] Hiding the "Loading..."
message in 8 seconds*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.806 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TIMER] _StoreProvider -
wlJsonStoreProvider - closeAll: 9ms*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.806 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TRACE] User
successfully logged out*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.807 WorkExecution[626:200217] [TIMER]
UserAuthenticationManager - logout: 10ms*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.807 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: Loading message
hidden by application = true*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.807 WorkExecution[626:200217] WARN: Loading message
hidden*

*2016-01-06 17:31:07.807 WorkExecution[626:200217] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT]
-[NotificationEx loadingStop:] in NotificationEx.m:150 :: Loading stop*

2016-01-06 17:31:08.802 WorkExecution[626:200217] ERROR: {"errorMsg":"The
user name and password combination that you entered is not valid."} 

2016-01-06 17:31:08.810 WorkExecution[626:200217] ERROR:
{"responseJSON":{"oslcError":"null oslcError","oslcMaxUserURL":"null
oslcMaxUserURL"},"status":"null status"}
```

Comment: are you connecting to the Maximo server via WIFI? Does that network allow connection to the Maximo server unrestricted, or at least on the ports you need access? I assume your connection from the desktop was hard wired and iPad is different connection method.

Answer (score 2):

from the stacktrace, i see:

> The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy
>   requires the use of a secure connection.*"

It looks like you are attempting to access the worklight over non-secure, but for iOS apps, you will need to access the secure url.  You may need to rebuild with the build.properties setting:

> worklight.server.protocol=https

And make sure that your worklight server is set up for SSL also.

Comment: Or, if this is in development, you can simply disable ATS: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/

Comment: There is also a Maximo Anywhere iFix for 7521 that you can request and download that makes those changes that Idan is recommending for you to enable iOS 9 to use non-secure MobileFirst servers.